# What does the "applyDefaultBehaviour" in RuntimeTypeModel.Add method do?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In protobuf-net, the `Add` method in `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel` takes two arguments, a `System.Type` and a boolean `applyDefaultBehaviour` - What does the boolean do? How does it affect things? When do I need to pass it true/false?

The xml doc says:

```
Whether to apply the inbuilt configuration patterns (via attributes etc), or
just add the type with no additional configuration (the type must then be manually configured)
```

That wasn't enough for me to understand, maybe it's just me...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `false`, then protobuf-net will do **nothing** to configure the type. It won't look at attributes, it won't look for common patterns. It will infer that you want to do all of that yourself, to build a custom model (perhaps for versioning reasons, or because the type is outside of your control and has attributes that are confusing protobuf-net).

Basically, pass `true` unless you know what you are doing ;p

---

Continuing from the comments: I **strongly** recommend that you simply swap to a separate DTO model. Serialize the data, not the implementation. As soon as I hear "Unity3D classes", my default is "that *probably* isn't the best option.

But as an example of manual configuration, here's a handy trick if `SomeType` (belonging to unity) cannot be serialized:

```
var metaType = model.Add(typeof(SomeType), false);
metaType.SetSurrogate(typeof(MyDTOThatLooksLikeSomeType));
```

where `MyDTOThatLooksLikeSomeType` is a regular DTO with attributes etc, but which **is** protobuf-net friendly (just regular serialization attributes), plus which has conversion operators to/from `SomeType`. Or you could do things manually:

```
var metaType = model.Add(typeof(SomeType), false).Add("Foo").Add(12, "Bar");
metaType.UseConstructor = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I don't own a type and want to add it to a model I have to pass false? (This is what I'm trying to know since I'm trying to use protobuf in Unity3D where I don't own a lot of its classes of course...) - Can you please say what type of configuration I must do if I pass false? " It will infer that you want to do all of that yourself" - could you define "all of that". Thank you.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I'm new to protobuf. What is a DTO - Isn't what you described for me to do is called a surrogate? - So let's say I wanted to serialize `UnityEngine.Vector3`, I create my own wrapper/surrogate class that looks like a Vector3 with pretty much all the annotations needed by protobuf and provide operator overloads between the two. Right?

Comment: @vexe yes, the surrogate would be a DTO - by "DTO" I simply mean "a simple type whose main job is to transfer data, perhaps for serialization". As for whether to choose a surrogate vs manual configuration: that depends a bit on **exactly** what `Vector3` looks like ;p If it *cannot* be made to play nicely, then a surrogate might be an option. The other option is to create an entire serialization model that *doesn't use `Vector3`*